# Systemd ExecStop run immediately after ExecStart

Tags: linux, systemd, centos-7

I have the following file in /etc/systemd/system/mytest.service

```
[Unit]
Description=My Test Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=mytestuser
Group=mytestuser
WorkingDirectory=/opt/mytest

ExecStart=/bin/echo "My Test Start!"

ExecStop=/bin/echo "My Test Stop!"

ExecReload=/bin/echo "My Test Restart!"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After running `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl start mytest` the following output can be seen from `journalctl -xe`

```
Jun 29 09:44:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting My Test Service...
-- Subject: Unit mytest.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mytest.service has begun starting up.
Jun 29 09:44:57 localhost.localdomain echo[4370]: My Test Start!
Jun 29 09:44:57 localhost.localdomain echo[4372]: My Test Stop!
Jun 29 09:44:57 localhost.localdomain polkitd[619]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:4364:694445 (system bus name :1.149, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_GB.UTF-8) (disconnected from
Jun 29 09:44:57 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started My Test Service.
-- Subject: Unit mytest.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit mytest.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
```

This shows the ExecStart command running, immediately followed by the ExecStop, why is this happening? Is there something missing from my .service file?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `echo` isn't forking - no child processes are left behind. What you need is a `oneshot` service, with `RemainAfterExit=true`. If you just change it to `oneshot`, you'll get the exact same behavior. The `RemainAfterExit` part tells it that even after the `ExecStart` exits, the service should still be considered running, so it should not run the `ExecStop`(s).